# Context is reset to null when browser URL is manually changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context, rerender

I have created `AuthContext` that holds currently logged in user:

```
// auth-context.ts
export interface IAuthContext {
  auth: IMe | null;
  setAuth: (user: IMe | null) => void;
}

const AuthContext = React.createContext<IAuthContext>({
  auth: null,
  setAuth: (auth: IMe | null) => {}
});

export default AuthContext;
```

The simplified main rendered `App` component where I use the context provider looks like this:

```
const App: FC = () => {

  const [auth, setAuth] = useState<IMe | null>(null); // problematic line

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{auth, setAuth}}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Main/>}/>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>}/>
          <Route path="/about" element={<About/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Overall, the application works fine.

However, when I navigate the application by **manual URL changes in the web browser**, followed-up by hitting the Enter (therefore: page refresh), then there is a problem with auth context reset to null...

I think when I change the URL manually then the whole `App` component is re-rendered and therefore the `AuthContext` state is reseted to null by the **problematic line**.

The idea is that the `Login` component is using the `setAuth` inside of it after the form-related promise is positively resolved.

Any tip how can I protect myself from that re-render problem, and therefore context resettng to default null value? I think this scenario is kind of basic, but I am beginner in frontend stuff. Thank you!

Comment: That's just how the web works. Navigating (even to a same-origin address) results in loading a new document. If that new document is the same SPA, then you start with fresh state. You can load previously saved state from something like `localStorage` or a cookie, or you can make an API request in a one-time `useEffect` to get the needed data and update your state. There are lots of well-documented techniques. Just query for something like "react persist state after reload" and start researching!